# Overloading << to output both key_type and mapped_type for a map

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class for a course catalog with a private variable of type `map<string, string> Courses`. I want to overload `<<` as a friend operator so that when I output for instance `Courses["TMA4100"]` it will output both `"TMA4100"` and the name of the course, not only the name. The reason is so that I can store the catalog in a file instead of having the catalog be erased when I shut down the program.

I'm not very familiar with maps, so I don't really know how to overload the operator to handle maps. This was my initial attempt:

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &outStream, const string coursecode){
outStream << coursecode << " " << Courses[coursecode];}
```

Now that I've thought about it, this doesn't make much sense at all because I won't be passing a string into the operator, but rather the map with a key. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no connection between `Courses["TMA4100"]` and `"TMA4100"` outside of the map.

Comment: What's wrong with just simply `std::cout << Courses["TMA4100"] << '\n';`?

Comment: You forget to return `outStream` in your `operator<<`

Comment: @Garf365 Yeah I know. My question was primarily about the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store the entire catalog, overload the operator for your own class, not for the map or a string.

Example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YourClass& catalog)
{
    for (const auto& entry: catalog.Courses)
    {
        os << entry.first << " " << entry.second << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

A suggestion about entry-wise access:

For added flexibility, create a class that holds course information and store those instead of strings:

```
struct CourseInfo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    StaffMember teacher;
    // ... more useful stuff ...
};
```

Your catalog will now be a `std::map<string, CourseInfo>`, and you can overload `<<` for `CourseInfo`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CourseInfo& info)
{
    os << info.name << " " << info.description << " " << info.teacher;
    return os;
}
```

and you can write (using a fictitious interface for your class):

```
YourClass catalog;
// ... populate the catalog
std::cout << catalog.courseInfo("TM4100") << std::endl;
```

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe I didn't overload it for the class...That was supremely stupid, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Btw, can you explain how the for-loop works? I haven't seen 'auto' before.

Comment: @Auclair It's a C++11 "range-based" loop. It's equivalent to `for (std::map<string, string>::const_iterator entry = catalog.Courses.begin(); entry != catalog.Courses.end(); ++entry)`, but much nicer. `auto` is a C++11 feature that makes the compiler infer the type for you.

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated. Thanks for the help though. Is it possible to overload it such that I can pass `catalog["TMA4100"]`and write that course to the file instead of writing the entire catalog to a file in one fell swoop? Your method is smoother no doubt, but I just want to learn :)

Comment: @Auclair I added a couple of suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you